# AWSS3 IOS framework is working fine below 10.0 on all IOS devices, but above 10.0 its working on iPad retina only

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

AWSS3 IOS framework is working fine below 10.0 on all IOS devices, but above 10.0 its working on iPad retina only (both simulator & device), not in the other IOS devices.

The app is not able to download any media file from S3 bucket except with iPad retina 10.0.1 and devices below 10.0 (Using Xcode 8.1)

Any help or suggestion regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any logs related to downloading from bucket?

Comment: No, it doesn't show any additional logs. @Badhan

Comment: Can you share some code where you download image from URL??

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more details? Which the SDK version you are using? Are you using authentication in your app?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. It was due to the Architecture Support. After importing my project to Xcode 8.1 it sets 'Valid architecture' as arm64, armv7, armv7s. Where, armv7 & armv7s is used for 32 Bit CPU and arm64 for the 64 Bit CPU.

Since my app was coded in older version of Xcode with 32 Bit valid architecture. So I added Standard architectures (armv7, armv64) in '**Architecture**' and removed arm64 from '**Valid architecture**'. Now it's working on all IOS devices perfectly.

Thanks to all of you for trying.